# Javascript not activating

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that is made to add `.fix` class to a `header` tag with `#header-wrap` id once the page is scrolled a certain amount, but for some reason nothing happens on scroll.
HTML:

```
<header id="header-wrap">
        <div id="redline"></div>
        <div id="velkommen"></div>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="indre">
                <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html">MCBERGBYS</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script>
var wrap = $("#header-wrap");

wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {

  if (this.scrollTop > 143) {
    wrap.addClass("fix");
  } else {
    wrap.removeClass("fix");
  }

});
</script>
```

I'm very new to javascipt so I bet something obvious is off. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and read the errors. There’s no reason to guess what went wrong.

Comment: are you referencing jQuery?

Comment: There's not enough context to help here. If nothing else you need to access the DOM after the DOM is actually ready, e.g., `$(function() { define wrap here, then define scroll handler }`

Comment: This should be javascript.

Comment: In the inspection tool's console it says:.Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)'

Comment: Here is the site live if it helps:
http://elevweb2.skit.no/1407aaar/rer/

Comment: @user3774924 Now that you’ve got the error, just search for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your `.on('scroll')` event to the `$(window)`, not to your `#header-wrap` element. This will check when the document is being scrolled up and down, as opposed to seeing when an individual element is being "scrolled" (like when you move up and down in a textarea).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Pretty much just how I spelled it out... Change `wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {` to `$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {`